# How to change relative URL to absolute URL in wget

Tags: unix, shell

I am writing a shell script to download and display the content from a site and I am saving this content to my local file system.

I have used the following command in the script to get the content:

```
/usr/sfw/bin/wget -q -p  -nH -np --referer=$INFO_REF --timeout=300 -P $TMPDIR $INFO_URL
```

where `INFO_REF` is the page where I need to display the content from `INFO_URL`.

The problem is that I am able to get the content (images/css) as an html page but in this html the links on the images and headlines,which are pointing to different site are not working and the path of the URLs (image links) are changing to my local file system path.

I tried adding the `-k` option in wget and with this option these URLs are pointing to correct location but now the images are not coming as the images path are changing from relative to absolute location. Without `-k` images are coming properly.

Please tell what option can I use so that images and the links in the page both come properly. Do I need to use two seperate wget commands one for images and another for links in the page?

Answer (score 2):

As per the wget manual:

> Actually, to download a single page
>   and all its requisites (even if they
>   exist on separate websites), and make
>   sure the lot displays properly
>   locally, this author likes to use a
>   few options in addition to -p:
>
> wget -E -H -k -K -p http://site/document

In order to adjust it to your needs:

```
/usr/sfw/bin/wget -q -E -H -k -K -p -nH --referer=$INFO_REF --timeout=300 -P $TMPDIR $INFO_URL
```

I removed the -np because I think it's wrong (maybe a page dependency is in the parent directory).